# Flask API Calling a Method from Itself

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, backend

My question is, can an endpoint in a Flask API call a method from another endpoint, that is a member of itself? Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: Each endpoint is a python function, why would it not work? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can indeed call another endpoint by using `redirect` with `url_for`

If this is something you are trying to achieve.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello world"


@app.route('/home')
def hello_again():
    return redirect(url_for('.hello_world'))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The request to `/home` will redirect you to `/`.